# Dynamic parsing of WSDL and invocation of WS with JAX-WS 2.0 and WSDL 2.0

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, wsdl2java

The big premise is that I am just starting learning WSs :) The last time I used them was a long time ago, so I do not precisely know how technology has evolved in these, say 6-7 years.

I would like to program a client which should be able to parse a WSDL file from its URI, and then dynamically be able to invoke the different operations the WS offers.
This should completely be done automatically: no generation of client stubs from the wsdl file or so on.
The technology I would like to use is
JAX-WS 2.0 (so Java)
WSDL 2.0

I am pretty sure there can be some code available, in order to take inspiration. Could somebody point me to this, please? (Clearly, if it exists)

Thanks, Franz

Comment: What is the purpose?  Being able to parse the WSDL and make automated calls to service operations is fine, but because the operations don't have any semantic meaning, you're going to have to tell it what operations to call, and what to pass.  So why do this instead of generating a client from the WSDL spec?

Comment: Because I do not want to directly use the WS: I would like to create a piece of intermediate code that is only a proxy between the WS and the real client. That's why I want to be able to parse the WSDL and to know how (operations and parameters) to send messages to the WS, without using the client generated through the WSDL spec. Just as explained here  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-udax/index.html but I would like to do that by using JAX-WS2.0 and WSDL 2.0 (only dynamic invocation, without dynamic discovery). Any idea?